# i am using angularjs, nodejs ,and mongodb for playlist manager and i get some console error like 404 for playlists file and se is connect successful

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, debugging, helper

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Playlist Manager</title>
  <script rel="shortcut icon icon" href="#"></script>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="songs.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <h1>Playlist Manager</h1>

      <input type="text" ng-model="playlistName" placeholder="Enter a playlist name">
      <button ng-click="addPlaylist()">Add Playlist</button>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Songs</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
            <td>{{playlist.name}}</td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="song in playlist.songs">
                  {{song.name}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button ng-click="removePlaylist(playlist)">Remove Playlist</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <h2>Add Song to Playlist</h2>

      <select ng-model="songName">
        <option ng-repeat="song in songs" value="{{song.name}}">{{song.name}}</option>
      </select>

      <select ng-model="playlistId">
        <option ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" value="{{playlist.id}}">{{playlist.name}}</option>
      </select>

      <button ng-click="addSongToPlaylist()">Add Song</button>

      <h2>Remove Song from Playlist</h2>

      <select ng-model="songName">
        <option ng-repeat="song in songs" value="{{song.name}}">{{song.name}}</option>
      </select>

      <select ng-model="playlistId">
        <option ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" value="{{playlist.id}}">{{playlist.name}}</option>
      </select>

      <button ng-click="removeSongFromPlaylist()">Remove Song</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playlists');

var PlaylistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  songs: [
    {
      name: String,
      artist: String
    }
  ]
});

var SongSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  artist: String
});

mongoose.model('Playlist', PlaylistSchema);
mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);

app.get('/playlists', function(req, res) {
  var playlists = [];
  Playlist.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      playlists = docs;
      res.json(playlists);
    }
  });
});

app.post('/playlists', function(req, res) {
  var playlist = new Playlist({
    name: req.body.name
  });

  playlist.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(playlist);
    }
  });
});

app.get('/playlists/:id', function(req, res) {
  var playlist = Playlist.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  });

  if (playlist) {
    res.json(playlist);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});

app.delete('/playlists/:id', function(req, res) {
  Playlist.remove({
    _id: req.params.id
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
});

app.post('/playlists/:id/songs', function(req, res) {
  var playlist = Playlist.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  });

  if (playlist) {
    var song = new Song({
      name: req.body.name,
      artist: req.body.artist
    });

    song.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        playlist.songs.push(song);
        playlist.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            res.json(playlist);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});

app.delete('/playlists/:id/songs/:songId', function(req, res) {
  var playlist = Playlist.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  });

  if (playlist) {
    var song = Song.findOne({
      _id: req.params.songId
    });

    if (song) {
      playlist.songs.remove(song);
      playlist.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(200);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000');
});
```

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.playlists = [];

  $http.get('/playlists').then(function(response) {
    $scope.playlists = response.data;
  });

  $scope.addPlaylist = function() {
    var playlist = {
      name: $scope.playlistName,
      songs: []
    };

    $http.post('/playlists', playlist).then(function(response) {
      $scope.playlists.push(response.data);
      $scope.playlistName = '';
    });
  };

  $scope.removePlaylist = function(playlist) {
    $http.delete('/playlists/' + playlist.id).then(function() {
      $scope.playlists = $scope.playlists.filter(function(p) {
        return p.id !== playlist.id;
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.addSongToPlaylist = function(playlist, song) {
    playlist.songs.push(song);
    $http.put('/playlists/' + playlist.id, playlist).then(function() {
    });
  };

  $scope.removeSongFromPlaylist = function(playlist, song) {
    var index = playlist.songs.indexOf(song);
    playlist.songs.splice(index, 1);
    $http.put('/playlists/' + playlist.id, playlist).then(function() {
    });
  };
});
```

`song.json`

```
[
    {
        "name": "Song 1",
        "artist": "Artist 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Song 2",
        "artist": "Artist 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "Song 3",
        "artist": "Artist 3"
    }
]
```

> that is full code when i am running this code it give me consoal error like this GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/playlists 404 (Not Found) so basically i can't access the playlists fill as i get 404 code error so problem is that i what should i do know to remove this error
> i have made many changes also check database name collection name but there is nothing help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.